# Counting Divisors of a number with restrictions on the divisors

Tags: python, performance, mathematics, factors

Given a fraction p/q, I want to count the number of unit fraction solutions

$$\frac{p}{q} = \frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v}$$

with some contraints

$$lower \le u \le upper$$

By manipulating the first equation and completing a square you arrive at a formula

$$(pu - q)(pv - q) = q^2$$

So the number of solutions is related to the divisors of q squared. If we only look at the smaller of two divisors (which we will call *a*), it is a solution if it produces a valid unit fraction (1 / *u*).

$$a = pu - q \implies u = \frac{a + q}{p}$$

We are interested in a divisor *a* iff

$$p*lower - q \le a \le p * upper - q, \space a \equiv -q \mod p$$

---

To compute the answer I first get the prime factorisation of q, then I  double each power to get the prime factorisation of q squared. Using this I enumerate over all the possible divisors, computing each one by trying all possible combination of powers. When I generate one I check if it matches the above requirements.

```
def factor_m(p, q, lower, upper):
    num = q
    factors = dict()
    count = 0
    while num % 2 == 0:
        num //= 2
        count += 1
    if count:
        factors[2] = count

    current = 3
    while num > 1:
        count = 0
        while num % current == 0:
            num //= current
            count += 1
        if count:
            factors[current] = count
        current += 2

    start, end = p * lower - q, p * upper - q
    mod = -q % p
    total = 0
    for powers in product(*(range((2 * v) + 1) for v in factors.values())):
        number = 1
        for b, _power in zip(factors, powers):
            number *= b ** _power

        if start <= number <= end and number % p == mod:
            total += 1

    return total
```

I'm calling this function **a lot** with reasonably big values of q (around 10**14 currently) so anything that saves time here is a massive boost.

Examples:

```
>>> factor_m(2, 7, 0, 50)  # 3
>>> factor_m(5, 1775025265104, 355005053021, 710010106041)  # 4101
>>> factor_m(737, 1046035200, 1926400, 2838630)  # 1
>>> factor_m(105467, 1231689911361, 11678439, 23356877)  # 0
```

---

**EDIT** To guarantee all solutions are distinct I only call the function with values that satisfy the constraint

$$lower \lt upper \le q$$

---

**EDIT2** I ran the full program through cProfile along with the program with modifications suggested by Josay. Unfortunately it is slower, I suspect because it almost doubles the number of function calls.

current_code - top 3 functions by time

```
672574 function calls (614969 primitive calls) in 19.526 seconds

 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  53273   18.818    0.000   18.893    0.000 fast.py:40(factor_m)
   2957    0.295    0.000    0.298    0.000 fast.py:8(factor_p1)
57606/1    0.149    0.000   19.525   19.525 fast.py:75(f)
```

With Josay's changes - top 3 functions by time

```
1163833 function calls (1106228 primitive calls) in 19.835 seconds

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function) 
53273   18.427    0.000   19.160    0.000 fast.py:61(factor_m)
53273    0.500    0.000    0.650    0.000 fast.py:42(get_factors)
 2957    0.297    0.000    0.301    0.000 fast.py:8(factor_v2)
```

Comment: Is `u` <= `v`? If not, it will "double-count" each not-repeating (commutative) pair of unit fractions, e.g. $$\frac{2}{7} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{28} = \frac{1}{28} + \frac{1}{4}$$ making u,v have a pair of values `[4,28]`, `[28,4]` that's counted twice.

Comment: @graham Good question! I'll make an edit to the post with this information. When I call the function I guarantee $$lower \lt upper \le q$$ which should ensure there are no duplicate solutions.

Comment: Also, I think you need to add `from itertools import product` to the top of your code.

Comment: @Graham To be exact, I would set upper = 2 * (7 / 2) = 7, since with 2 fractions the bigger of the two could not be any smaller and still form solutions. So I would call the function like this: factor_m(2, 7, lower, 7)
From this, end = 2 * 7 - 7 = 7, so I would check for values of u between start (inclusive) and 7 (exclusive). So I would want to find for the above exactly one solution, the first one.

Answer (score 1):

**Code organisation**

In order to improve the code performances, if could be a good idea to make the easier to understand and easier to change.

You could:

- split your code into smaller functions
- add documentation
- add tests
- reuse existing data structures such as [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

We'd get something along the lines of:

```
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter
import time

def get_factors(n):
    """Get factor for integer n

    Return the factorisation of n as a dictionnary
    mapping prime factors to their exponents."""
    factors = Counter()
    d = 2
    while n % d == 0:
        n //= d
        factors[d] += 1
    d = 3
    while n > 1:
        while n % d == 0:
            n //= d
            factors[d] += 1
        d += 2
    return factors


def factor_m(p, q, lower, upper):
    """Return the number of unit fractions solutions to:
       p   1   1
       - = - + - with lower <= u <= upper
       q   u   v

    The equation is equivalent to ..."""
    factors = get_factors(q)
    start, end = p * lower - q, p * upper - q
    mod = -q % p
    total = 0
    for powers in product(*(range((2 * v) + 1) for v in factors.values())):
        number = 1
        for b, _power in zip(factors, powers):
            number *= b ** _power

        if start <= number <= end and number % p == mod:
            total += 1

    return total

t = time.time()
assert factor_m(2, 7, 0, 50) == 3
assert factor_m(5, 1775025265104, 355005053021, 710010106041) == 4101
assert factor_m(737, 1046035200, 1926400, 2838630) == 1
assert factor_m(105467, 1231689911361, 11678439, 23356877) == 0
print(time.time() - t)
```

**Simple mathematical optimisation**

A trivial optimisation can be added to the logic performing the prime decomposition: for all divisors d, d * d <= n. Thus we can stop the search earlier (and the remaining part is known to be a prime).

```
while n >= d * d:
    while n % d == 0:
        n //= d
        factors[d] += 1
    d += 2
if n >= 1:    # to avoid 1 as a factor
    factors[n] += 1
```

This makes the code only very slightly faster as the bottleneck is not in that part of the code.

**Limit the number of operations performed/limit accesses to `factors`**

When iterating over `factors`, you get the values to create range of exponents (0, 1, 2, ...) and then, in the loop, you zip this to the keys to generate the `prime**exponent` value.

You could feed into the `product` function, the values `prime**exponent` already computed so that you limit the number of operations (`**` mostly) and you access `factors` in a single place.

This would give something like:

```
def get_divisors_for_square_of(n):
    """"Generate all divisors for n^2.

    Use the factorisation of n and double the exponents."""
    factors = get_factors(q)
    powers_list = [[p**v for v in range(2 * v + 1)] for p, v in factors.items()]
    for powers in product(*powers_list):
       number = 1
       for p in powers:
           number *= p
       yield number
```

On my setup, this halves the computing time.

**Final code**

```
import itertools
import collections

def get_factors(n):
    """Generate factors for integer n."""
    d = 2
    while n % d == 0:
        n //= d
        yield d
    d = 3
    while n >= d * d:
        while n % d == 0:
            n //= d
            yield d
        d += 2
    if n >= 1:    # to avoid 1 as a factor
        yield n


def get_divisors_for_square_of(n):
    """"Generate all divisors for n^2.

    Use the factorisation of n and double the exponents."""
    factors = collections.Counter(get_factors(n))
    powers_list = [[p**v for v in range(2 * v + 1)] for p, v in factors.items()]
    for powers in itertools.product(*powers_list):
       number = 1
       for p in powers:
           number *= p
       yield number


def factor_m(p, q, lower, upper):
    """Return the number of unit fractions solutions to:
       p   1   1
       - = - + - with lower <= u <= upper
       q   u   v

    The equation is equivalent to:
        puv = q(u + v)
    or
        (pu-q) (pv-q) = q^2
    which boils down to finding divisors of q.
    Let a = pu - q, then u = (a + q) / p when it gives an integer
    which is when (a + q ) mod p == 0.
    Also, we want p * lower - q <= a <= p * upper - q.
    ....
    Solution for 2/7 are (u, v) = [(4, 28), (7, 7), (28, 4)].
    """
    start, end = p * lower - q, p * upper - q
    return sum(1
               for a in get_divisors_for_square_of(q)
               if start <= a <= end and (a + q) % p == 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    t = time.time()
    for i in range(5):
        assert factor_m(2, 7, 0, 50) == 3
        assert factor_m(2, 21, 0, 500) == 9
        assert factor_m(5, 1775025265104, 355005053021, 710010106041) == 4101
        assert factor_m(737, 1046035200, 1926400, 2838630) == 1
        assert factor_m(105467, 1231689911361, 11678439, 23356877) == 0
    print(time.time() - t)
```

*I'll update the solution if I find other things.*

Comment: I tried looping until d*d, but I couldn't measure any noticeable difference. Splitting the code out into a function actually worsens the time on my machine. I'll edit in cProfile metrics.

Comment: I was tweaking with the code trying to get a better understanding of it before being able to find micro optimisation, better algorithm or mathematical insight but I've thought a lot about this and was unable to find a real way to improve things so far....

Comment: @spyr03 I think things should be faster now. Please let me know...